# Stop rails from including the record in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this code here which takes two params search and search_lang. Now sometimes if the name of a note has the search term in it and the tags have the same search term in it, it will return the same record twice. Any way to stop this from happening?

```
if search_lang == "all-notes"
  notes.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%") + notes.tagged_with(search)
elsif search.blank?
  notes.where("lower(coding_lang) LIKE ?", "%#{search_lang.downcase}%") + notes.tagged_with(search) 
else
  notes.where("lower(coding_lang) LIKE ?", "%#{search_lang.downcase}%").where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{search.downcase}%") + notes.tagged_with(search)
end
```

Comment: You mean `duplicate records`? then use `distinct`

Comment: Add both objects and use uniq for remove duplicates like suggested by RSB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uniq`

```
(notes.where(conditions) + notes.tagged_with(search)).uniq
```